# Send Files with FormData to Nodejs server using RTK Query and React Native Expo

Tags: node.js, expo, multipartform-data, rtk-query, expo-image-picker

I want to send a file to the server picked using expo-document-picker OR expo-image-picker. The result object from picker is stored in providerDetails.id like this:

{"assets": [{"mimeType": "application/pdf", "name": "ID.pdf", "size": 273445, "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/DocumentPicker/4eff3862-4978-4b3a-8e1a-fb0af846fe83.pdf"}], "canceled": false}

Tried "fetch" and other methods. They do not work with expo. Following code gives Parsing error, most probably by multer because it is not getting the file in request:

```js
try {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("firstName", providerDetails.firstName);
    formData.append("lastName", providerDetails.lastName);
    formData.append("id", {
        uri: providerDetails.id.assets[0].uri,
        name: providerDetails.id.assets[0].fileName || providerDetails.id.assets[0].name,
        type: providerDetails.id.assets[0].mimeType,
    } as any );

    const data = await requestProviderAccount(formData).unwrap();
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error submitting provider account request:", error);
}
```

Error submitting provider account request: {"data": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\maizn\Documents\Projects\Helphive Project\Codebase\helphive-backend\uploads\1000070776.jpg'", "error": "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: E", "originalStatus": 500, "status": "PARSING_ERROR"}

Redux API Slice:

```js
import { apiSlice } from "../../app/api/apiSlice";

export const providerApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    overrideExisting: true,
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        requestProviderAccount: builder.mutation({
            query: (formData) => {
                
                return {
                    url: "provider/request-provider-account",
                    method: "POST",
                    body: formData,
                };
            },
        }),
    }),
});

export const { useRequestProviderAccountMutation } = providerApiSlice;
```

My server-side endpoint:

```js
import express from "express";
import multer from "multer";
import { handleRequestProviderAccount } from "../controllers/providerController";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "./uploads");
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const providerRoute = express.Router();

providerRoute.post(
    "/request-provider-account", 
    upload.fields([
        { name: 'id', maxCount: 1 },
        { name: 'resume', maxCount: 1 },
        { name: 'dbs', maxCount: 1 },
        { name: 'profile', maxCount: 1 }
    ]),
    handleRequestProviderAccount
);

export default providerRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```js
import { apiSlice } from "../../app/api/apiSlice";

export const providerApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    overrideExisting: true,
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        requestProviderAccount: builder.mutation<any, any>({
            query: (formData) => {
                return {
                    url: "provider/request-provider-account",
                    method: "POST",
                    formData: true, // set formData to true
                    body: formData,
                };
            },
        }),
    }),
});

export const { useRequestProviderAccountMutation } = providerApiSlice;
```

I thought Content-Type: multipart/form-data was set automatically, but didn't know there was a new term also.